# How to assign to a base class object when inheriting from builtin objects?

Tags: python, inheritance, built-in

I'm trying to extend the Python built-in list object to include metadata.  I would like to be able to assign by reference to the base class object in some cases for efficiency.

For example:

```
class meta(list):
    def __init__(self, data=None, metadata=None):
        if data is not None:
            super().__init__(data) # performs a copy of data
        else:
            super().__init__()
        self.metadata = metadata

    def foo(self):
        new_data = [ i for i in range(10) ]
        return meta(new_data, "my meta data")
```

This works as expected.  The call to `foo` returns a new `meta` object with the values 0-9 in it.  However, the list created and assigned to `new_data` in the list comprehension is copied inside the initializer of meta due to the call to the base class initializer.  This additional copy is unnecessary as it could simply assign the reference of new_data to the inherited list object as no other references to it could exist after exiting `foo`.

What I'm trying to describe is something like this:

```
class meta(list):
    def __init__(self, data=None, metadata=None):
        if data is not None:
            super().__init__(data) # performs a copy of data
        else:
            super().__init__()
        self.metadata = metadata

    def foo(self):
        result = meta(None, "my meta data") # an efficient initialization
        new_data = [ i for i in range(10) ]
        super(list, result) = new_data # just assign the reference instead of copying
        return result
```

But I know this is not correct syntactically.  However, it does describe what I'm trying to accomplish.  The intent is the `new_data` list object would simply be referred to by the new `meta` object via a reference to it being assigned to the underlying list object.

I know I could use a list member object instead of inheriting from list but that causes other inefficiencies because now all of the list attributes have to be defined in the `meta` class and would get wrapped in another layer of function calls.

So…my questions are:

- Is there a way to do this at all?
- Can I access the underlying object as an independent object from the subclass?
- Can it be implemented cleanly without creating more overhead than I'm trying to remove?
- Is there some obscure `__assign__` method available that isn't an undocumented 'feature' of the language?

Answer (score 0):

The instance of `meta` is, necessarily, a *new* instance, and you assign to *names*, not objects. You can't simply replace the new instance with an instance of `list`. That is, the new instance of `meta` doesn't contain a reference to another `list` instance; it *is* the list instance, just with a `__class__` attribute that refers to `meta`, not `list`.

If you don't want to make a copy of the argument, don't make a list argument in the first place.

```
class meta(list):
    def __init__(self, data=None, metadata=None):
        if data is not None:
            super().__init__(data) # performs a copy of data
        else:
            super().__init__()
        self.metadata = metadata

    def foo(self):
        new_data = range(10)
        return meta(new_data, "my meta data")
```

`list.__init__` isn't exepecting a list; it's just expecting an *iterable*, references to the elements of which can be added to the just-constructed list.

You would probably want to override `__new__` anyway, since `list.__new__` already contains the logic that decides if there is an iterable available to pass to `__init__`.

```
class meta(list):
    def __new__(cls, *args, metadata=None, **kwargs):
        new_list = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        new_list.metadata = metadata
        return new_list

    def foo(self):
        return meta(range(10), metadata="my meta data")
```

(And finally, `foo` should probably be a static method or a class method, since it makes no use of the `meta` instance that invokes it.)

Comment: I was trying to simplify the example.  Consider the `new_data` object in method `foo` to be a bit more complicated than a simple range of numbers.  In either case, wouldn't the call to `__new__` result in calling `list.__init__` which would then, via the iterable, copy the elements of the list provided to the new list?  This copy operation is what I'm trying to avoid when it is not really necessary.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not copying the elements, but rather creating a new list of references *to* the elements. The copy is necessary, because there simply isn't just a single refernce to the list you are passing in. The instance of `meta` *is* the list; it's not an object with a reference *to* a list. You may be using C++ as your mental model, where an instance of a subclass does behave like a wrapper around an instance of the parent class. That's not true in Python; an object just "is", and it has a reference to its class (which itself has a refernce to its parent class)....

Comment: ... Instances treat all its instance attributes the same, regardless of which method might set the attribute. Inheritance only determines how names are looked up if they aren't found in the instance dictionary.

Comment: So...  the meta class is a pseudonym for a signal class with data points held in the list.  These data points are immutable int's, float's, complex's, or possibly something derived from them.  Big picture is these lists can be a few million points in length.  I want to do operations on and between these signal objects.  The operation will necessarily generate the result in a list and calling the initializer of the signal object to return it will result in copying all that data when it isn't really necessary.  But I think writing this comment has given me an idea.  I'll post again if it works.

Comment: You probably don't want to use inheritance then, but rather composition. You also probably don't want to be using an actual Python `list` to store the values, but something like a `numpy` array, which will use *far* less overhead.

Comment: Actually, I am using numpy underneath.  I'm not convinced it doesn't suffer from similar issues though.  Anyway, I have evidence the solution I provided gains in efficiency, thanks to your enlightened conversation which helped to achieve it.

Comment: The same issue *would* apply with creating an instance of a subclass of `array` from an existing value of type `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Although @chepner didn't answer my question directly, I got some encouragement from them and came up with the following solution.

Consider having two `meta` objects and we want to add the underlying `list` objects together element by element.

The most straight forward answer is similar to my original post.  I'll leave the error checking to the reader to implement.

```
class meta(list):
    def __init__(self, data, metadata):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.metadata = metadata

    def __add__(self, other):
        return meta([self[i] + other[i] for i in range(len(self))], self.__metadata)

a = meta([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "meta data")
b = meta([6, 7, 8, 9, 0], "more data")
a + b
[7, 9, 11, 13, 5]
```

Note:  The meta data is just there to complete the example and I know I left out checks for making sure the b list isn't shorter than the a list.  However, the operation works as expected.  It's also easy to see the `list` created by the list comprehension is later copied completely in `meta.__init__` at the call to `list.__init__` via the `super().__init__(...)` call.  This second copy is what I wanted to avoid.

Thanks to @chepner's identification of `list.__init__` taking an iterable, I came up with the following solution.

```
class meta_add_iterable:
    def __init__(self, *data):
        self.data = data # copies only the references to the tuple of arguments passed in
        self.current = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.current += 1
        if self.current < len(self.data[0]):
            return sum([ i[self.current] for i in self.data ])
        raise StopIteration

class meta(list):
    def __init__(self, data, metadata):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.metadata = metadata

    def __add__(self, other):
        return meta(meta_add_iterable(self, other), self.metadata)

a = meta([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "meta data")
b = meta([6, 7, 8, 9, 0], "more data")
a + b
[7, 9, 11, 13, 5]
```

In the above implementation, there is no interim list created via list comprehension in the `meta.__add__` method.  Instead, we simply pass the two `meta` objects (`self` and `other`) to the iterator object.  Here the only copy that is done is to copy the references to the original meta objects so the iterator can refer to them.  Then the call to `meta.__init__` passes the iterator in instead of an already created list.  The `list.__init__` method simply creates the list from this iterator which means each referred to meta object is accessed only once to retrieve its data and the result is only written once in the `list.__init__` method.  The secondary copy is completely elided in this implementation because the add operation is actually deferred until the iterators `__next__` method is called in `list.__init__`.

The best part is we don't need to check if we are initializing from a list object or an iterator!

I know there are plenty of things that can go wrong as it stands.  I left out all of the error checking and such so just the process was visible to the reader.

I'm not sure if implementing it using the `__new__` method would still be better, as suggested by @chepner.  Personally, I can't see the benefit.  Maybe @chepner can expand on why that may still be the better solution.  Either way, this seems to have answered my question and I'm hopeful it may help others.